# An inequality over determinant of Gramian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Suppose $n$ vectors $v_1, v_2,...,v_p,v_{p+1},...,v_n$. Let $G(v_1,...,v_n)$ the Gramian matrix of $v_1,...v_n$.

Prove that : $|G(v_1,...,v_p)|\cdot|G(v_{p+1},...v_n)| \geq |G(v_1,...,v_n)|$.

For $p=1$, it could be proved by its positive definiteness, but I have no idea for $p\ge2$...

The definition of Gramian matrix is here: [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)

Thanks a lot ~

Comment: [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) and [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) are useful here.

Comment: @user1551 I don't really get it for $p>1$...Suppose that 4 block matrices in $|G(v_1,...,v_n)|$ are $A, B, B^T, C$. By using Schur complement, we got $|G(v_1,...v_n)|=|A|\cdot |C-B^TA^{-1}B|$ and I could only prove the case when $C$ is $1\times1$(by positive definiteness)

I don't know if it's the same idea for higher dimensions...